# Relationship between Hartley entropy and local dimension

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, entropy, spin-chains, tensor-network

I am recently reading a paper about entanglement entropy. It mentions that if we consider a 1D spin chain and write a pure state in the matrix product state:

\begin{align}
|\psi\rangle = A^{\sigma_1}A^{\sigma_2}\cdots A^{\sigma_i}A^{\sigma_{i+1}}\cdots A^{\sigma_N}\left|\sigma_1\cdots\sigma_N\right\rangle
\end{align}

And we treat spins $1,\dots,i$ to be subsystem A and spins $i+1,\dots,N$ to be subsystem B, then we can define the $n$-th Renyi entropy between A and B:

\begin{align}
\rho &= \left|\psi\right\rangle\left\langle \psi\right|\\
\rho_B &= \text{Tr}_A\rho\\
S_n(B) &= \frac{1}{1-n}\log\text{Tr}\rho_B^n
\end{align}

For the zeroth Renyi entropy, it equals

\begin{align}
S_0(B) =\log r
\end{align}

Here $r$ is the number of nonzero eigenvalues of $\rho_B$ and it is also the Schmidt rank. But the paper also says that $r$ equals $d_{i,i+1}$, the local dimension between $A^{\sigma_i}$ and $A^{\sigma_{i+1}}$ in MPS. Why is it true? How to prove it?

References:

1. https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevX.7.031016 Appendix A Eqn.A11.

Answer (score 0):

It is only true that $r\le d_{i,i+1}$.

This is easy to see: First, write the matrix products using explicit sums over the matrix indices. Then, the only summation index which couples the subsystems A and B is the index from the matrix product $A^{\sigma_i}A^{\sigma_{i+1}}$, which can take $d_{i,i+1}$ values.

Thus, the state can be written as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{d_{i,i+1}} |a_k\rangle|b_k\rangle\ .
$$
The number of terms in the sum *upper bounds* the number of terms in the Schmidt decomposition. Thus, $r\le d_{i,i+1}$.

Of course, if you pose additional conditions on the MPS (like a "nice" canonical form), it might also hold that $r=d_{i,i+1}$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I believe. If you are interested the paper, it is [link](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.7.031016) Appendix A. I guess they are talking about the possible minimal d_{i,i+1}?  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hm, that's two pages. You don't seriously expect anyone to read two full pages just to spot what you are after?

Comment: Sorry, it is my fault. In fact, I just mean eqn. A11. I apologize for it.

Comment: Ideally, you should edit your question to include this information.

Comment: I guess that's what "In an efficient representation" right before (A11) is supposed to indicate.